# Sum quantity in a lodash grouped array

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I have a groupedBy subscription lodash array, and I want to sum the quantity property and return the value.

Example

```
{
  sub_1MT4LuP6DArCazGmEdJd: [
    {
      id: 'prod_HleWjM6culM',
      quantity: 1,
    },
    {
      id: 'prod_HleWjM6culM',
      quantity: 3,
    }
  ]
}
```

The output should be:

```
{
  sub_1MT4LuP6DArCazGmEdJd: [
    {
      totalQuantity: 4,
    },
  ]
}
```

Which is the best way to do this sum of values in a lodash grouped array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`_.sumBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/#sumBy).

```js
let o = {
  sub_1MT4LuP6DArCazGmEdJd: [
    {
      id: 'prod_HleWjM6culM',
      quantity: 1,
    },
    {
      id: 'prod_HleWjM6culM',
      quantity: 3,
    }
  ]
};
o.sub_1MT4LuP6DArCazGmEdJd = [{totalQuantity:
  _.sumBy(o.sub_1MT4LuP6DArCazGmEdJd, 'quantity')}];
console.log(o);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```